# how can i fix following VBA code

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

this code is to populate textboxes in form where sql query is fatching data from table RR_info on the behalf of hr_id. it compare hr_id of rr_info with the bounded value of listbox.

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()
 Dim SQL As String
 Dim db As Database
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

 SQL = "select * from RR_info where hr_id = " & Forms![hhrrr]![List38] & ";"
 Set db = CurrentDb
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
                                'DoCmd.RunSQL SQL 'at this point it gives me error 2342
 Me.RR_ID.value = rs!RR_ID
 Me.HR_ID.value = rs!HR_ID 
 Me.Room_No.value = rs![Room No] 
 Me.No_of_Beds.value = rs!No_of_Beds
 Me.Room_Category.value = rs!Room_Category

 Set rs = Nothing
 Set db = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need string "DoCmd.RunSQL SQL".
And it is better to use .Value insted of .Text

Comment: by applying your suggestions the problem isn't solved but a error occur and error code is 2448 and "YOU CAN'T ASSIGN VALUE TO THIS OBJECT".

Comment: runtime error 3075.   Syntax error missing operator in query expression 'hr_id='.

Comment: one more thing i have delete the row source property from property window and now VBA code above is doing everything.